# How to share Repository and Service classes between 2 projects

Tags: java, spring, class, share

I am working on 2 projects, one web app (Spring MVC) and one standalone backend service application (Spring boot) that heavily interact together.  I am using hibernate for both and they are both coded using the Netbeans IDE.

My "issue" is that i end up with duplicate code in both project, mainly in the Repository and Service layers.  My entities are obviously also duplicated since both projects use the same database.

Is there a way to make some sort of class library (a third project maybe?) and put all the common code in there?  If that is indeed possible, how do you then change each project so they can still access this code as if it were part of them? I was thinking of putting all my Repositories, Services and entities in there to avoid code duplication and greatly reduce the risk of error.

Thank you!

Comment: You could package the shared libraries with maven and use them as a dependency in both projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate those `Repository` and `Service` classes to a submodule.

The structure looks like:

```
-- your app
  -- api    (dependent on `common` module)
  -- webapp (dependent on `common` module)
  -- common
```

Then the problem is to initialize beans inside common module. AFAIK, you have two options:

1. In `@Configuration` class of `api` or `webapp` module, add base packages of `common` module to component scan packages
2. In `api` or `webapp` resources folder, add Spring configuration factory 
   /src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories
   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=your.path.AutoConfiguration

   Define service/repository `@Bean` inside `AutoConfiguration` class

Comment: That will definitely be useful information.  To start with though, i'd like to know how to package them in the first place.  I was thinking of creating a third maven project and call it MDHIS_Common.  I would then create a similar package structure, put the common classes in there and package this project as a jar file.  Finally, i would need to somehow tell both my maven projects to make use of this jar and delete the "local" copies of each class.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. Add local maven dependency is easy. Pump up google for some examples. The real tough is when you wire your bean together, which I already provided some options

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**I am assuming in this answer your projects are connected to each other**

You can set multiple `properties` within one `Spring` project, where you store your database connection parameters etc. with the help of multiple property files.
For example:

`application-web.properties`

`application-backend.properties`

You can use these in your project, by activating the needed properties file per application. The profile names will be `web` and `backend` in these cases.

When using maven, this is the command line I am using:

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=<<profile>>`

Now, back to your java code. 
If there are classes only one of your application is using, you can specify this by 'profile'. Example:

```
@Controller

@Profile({ "web" })
public class WebEndpoint {
}
```

This way you can make the shared code available for both applications, without duplicating most of the code.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  However, i don't understand how this can help me package my common classes into one (i can only assume) jar and make them visible to each project.  It frankly doesn't matter that they are all visible to both projects, i just don't want to have 2 copies of each repository, service and entity class.  I also want to make sure that Spring will play nicely with this setup and how exactly to implement it.